# Display method in Fragment/Set TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I can't find any example online about how to place a method into a TextView so it shows in the fragment when the application is opened. I think I remember it being something like

```
+ "text" + getDeviceName() + "more text"
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="@string/overview_one"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,  false);

        return rootView;

    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
      String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
          return capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}


private String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
      if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
          return s;
       } else {
           return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
       }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you specify it more clearly, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you're asking. So here goes...
The Activity.OnCreate method occurs when the application is open. However you can set a text into TextView by sample code:

```
TextView itemText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
itemText.setText("text " + getDeviceName());
```

If you want to hide the view in code instead of the xml, do this:

```
itemText.setVisibility(false);
```

You can place the code into onCreateView method in your fragment class, unless you want to make a new (public) method.
I hope this is close to what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't want to set random text ("Hi, new text") I want to show the `public String getDeviceName()` method output in the TextView. 

`text.setText("text " + getDeviceName() + "text" )`

Comment: Thats my point I don't know where to place the code in the HomeFragment.java file. The code I need is more than is what your example shows.
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Display-battery-information-of-android-device
I get

Comment: Again, I edit my answer. You may place the code in the onCreateView method. Try that out to see if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //I am not sure you want exactly, but 
     //Write Down a Code onCreateView
     TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

     //Call  method write now
     String s = getDeviceName();
     tv.setText(s);
```